# Running taurus command from master node on azure containers which is unable to reach slave node due to error in method java.rmi.MarshalException

Tags: azure, jmeter, containers, taurus

Error at master node trying to connect to remote jmter slave node in same network

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that at least port 1099 is open, check out [How to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) article for more details.

Apart from port 1099 you need to open:

- The port you specify as the `server.rmi.localport` on slaves
- The port you specify as the `client.rmi.localport` on master

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)
- [JMeter Remote Testing: Using a different port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange)